# App built with py2app terminates at OAuth request line

Tags: python, oauth, py2app

In short, I have a python module that I'm building into an app with py2app. When I run the app in  distribution (not alias), it hangs at this line

```
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
```

It runs fine when using the alias. Suggestions? 
More info: I'm just making this an  app through py2app. http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/source/browse/get_access_token.py

Comment: have you tried running the app from the command line? That is, run MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp in the terminal.  This might show some more information on what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem. It looks like py2app is stripping essential parts of requests. That would be interesting to see why. To fix this, add the following options for py2app in your setup.py:

```
OPTIONS = {'includes': ['requests'],
           'packages': ['requests']}
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried that but my app still crashes on launch